# How to understand Annotations in Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin

i'm a really noob with Vaadin and Java...

I have this snippets :

```
@com.vaadin.ui.ClientWidget(ModuleName.class)
public class HomeScreen extends Screen { ... }
```

What does these annotations meaning with Vaadin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SuppressWarnings is just a way to tell Eclipse not to show warnings for some particular elements in the class. In this case Eclipse won't whine about the missing serial uid. They are not defined because they aren't needed.

Vaadin components have two parts; server side and client side. The @ClientWidget annotation is meant to be placed in the server side component and it binds the server side component to the client side component. Reference: [Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/gwt.server-side.html#N364A3).

You don't have to mind the @ClientWidget annotation if you aren't developing a client side widget by yourself. If you are a beginner, I suggest you don't bother yourself with the client side development just yet.